# How can I execute Web Service Task in SSIS without using output variable?

Tags: ssis

I have created an SSIS project, running a web service task to execute a function. Everything runs fine, but I get an error on the assignment of the output variable: 
`The type of variable being assigned to the variable differs from the current variable type.`

I actually do not need for it to return an output variable, however, the task properties do not give me an option to not have an output variable.

Currently the webservice is a `void` type, but I also tried having it return `true` and set the variable type to a `boolean`.  I got the same error.  In this case, I am not sure what I need to do to assign the variable, but I'd rather it just not be looking for an output variable at all.

Can someone help me figure out how to either

1. not have an output variable or
2. assign an output of **true** / **1** / **""** whatever arbitrarily so that it does not return an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I ran into the same problem so worth posting an answer.

As you say, SSIS does not actually allow you not to have an output variable.  If your webservice method returns void, you need to set up a variable of type Object and use that as the output variable.